# How would this be converted from Obj-C to Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, xcode6

I am trying to re-write an app in swift which is currently in Objective-C. How would I change this single line into Swift, as my current attempt does not prove correct

```
Tabata *tabata = [notification object];
```

Here is the entire function:

```
- (void)stateChanged:(NSNotification*)notification
{
if (enabled)
{
    Tabata *tabata = [notification object];
    switch (tabata.getState) {
        case EXERCISE:
        case RELAXATION:
            [player play];
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
}
```

And here is what I've converted into Swift:

```
func stateChanged(notifcation: NSNotification) {
    if enabled {

        var tabata: Tabata! = notification.object //error "Use of unresolved identifier 'notification'"
        switch tabata.getState() {
        case .EXERCISE: fallthrough
        case .RELAXATION:
            player.play()
            break

        default:
            break

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a typo: your method signature lists the parameter as `notifcation`, while the method body is trying to use `notification`. Other than that, everything looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, although now it is giving me the error "'AnyObject?' is not convertible to 'Tabata!'"

Comment: nevermind, I got it by tacking on 'as! Tabata!'

Comment: I would like to say as a word of warning that if you are converting your code base to swift then if something has the potential to be nil just treat it as an optional (using the `?` syntax) as oppose to a implicitly unwrapped optional (`!`) as you have in the code above. This only opens up the opportunity for your app to crash at run time if a nil suddenly appears somewhere where it can't be dealt with. If you treat it as an optional then the compiler will help you in ensuring that `nil` is never present where it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swift you have to downcast objects of type AnyObject rather then declare the type

```
   var tabata = notification.object as! Tabata
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func stateChanged(notification: NSNotification) {
    if(enabled) {
        var tabata: Tabata = notification.object as! Tabata
        switch tabata.getState() {
        case .EXERCISE:
            fallthrough
        case .RELAXATION:
            player.play()
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!